# Load Angular components/Modules in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have a .Net Web application (aspx pages & not mvc) and I want to introduce some Angular components to it. Basically, there will be a Master Page and the asp content will refer to a aspx page and part of that aspx page will need to show some Angular component. Is there anyone that could help me with this situation. And most importantly, I don't want to use any routing and there will be many such aspx pages loading different components.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Components](https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction#:%7E:text=Web%20components%20are%20a%20set,web%20pages%20and%20web%20apps.&text=Web%20components%20are%20based%20on%20existing%20web%20standards.) technology is what you need. Here is the documentation for Angular port of Web Components: [Angular elements overview](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

It is not that straightforward task though. You might need to refactor the Angular components and for sure good knowledge of FE would be required.